# Develop and deploy changes to apache-superset

Tags: apache-superset

I'm evaluating apache-superset against other and therefore looking into how to do custom development to the project and then deploy these changes.

I followed the "CONTRIBUTING.MD" file in the github for instruction on how to set up the project for local development. 
But after doing this and making changes to either front or backend, is there a process for how to deploy these change in a production environment?

Is there any easy/right way to do this? Is docker recommended for this? And does anyone know how I would go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Python is build using the Flask microframework. It can be deployed by building a distribution wheel file by running the command below at the root of the git repository.

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

This will generate a wheel file located a the relative path /dist

Go on and install the wheel file via the command below

```
pip install <wheel file name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild the docker image with modifications using docker-composer.

```
# delete the previous docker image
docker rmi superset_superset_1
# After modifying the code base, rebuild docker
cd incubator-superset/contrib/docker
docker-compose run --rm superset ./docker-init.sh
docker-compose up
```

I found this [article](https://medium.com/@nileshxbhosale/apache-superset-a-cost-effective-alternative-to-quick-sight-for-data-lake-668868fe51c7), a good guide on deploying superset.